# $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus A$ deformation retracts onto $S^1 \vee S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Hatcher says the following:

**The complement $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus A$ of a single circle $A$ deformation retracts onto a wedge sum $S^1 \vee S^2$.**

He then goes on to explain it, but I do not understand the explainations (pages 46/47, example 1.23).
I'm staring at the following picture: [image]

The first is $S^1 \vee S^2$ and the second is homotopy equivalent to the first. So the question is, why is the second space homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus A$?

Hatcher says, we push points from outside the sphere onto the sphere. So far, so good.
Points that are outside of $A$ can also be pushed onto the sphere. What about points inside $A$? Can we contract them to a point and stretch it from one end of the sphere to the other to get the desired space?

Comment: I think that 5 years old kids don't know what algebraic topology is :P

Comment: It may be useful to write down which part of the explanation you are having trouble understanding, so we get a sense of what you know. Otherwise I fear the potential answers may not help you.

Comment: Yes, let me edit my question, 1 sec

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Say the circle has radius $1$, center at the origin, and lies in the $xz$-plane. Now let $S^2$ be embedded with center in the origin and radius $2$. Everything outside the sphere deformation retracts onto the sphere.

For every point $x$ inside the sphere, if it's on the $y$-axis, leave it. Otherwise, there is a point $p$ on the circle that is closest to it. Now let $x$ move directly away from $p$ until it either hits the $y$-axis or the sphere, whichever comes first (this is continuous because the line between $p$ and $x$ is coplanar to the $y$-axis, so there are no points that "just misses" the $y$-axis and goes past it). You've now created the second space.

Comment: Great, i got it now, thanks

Comment: How exactly do we know each line is coplanar to the y-axis?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 If you're uncomfortable with that definition of $p$, we can instead look at the plane containing $x$ and the $y$-axis, and let $p$ be the point where this plane intersects the circle, on the same side of the $y$-axis as $x$. It turns out to be the same $p$, but maybe with this description it's a bit clearer what's going on.

Comment: @Arthur Do you mean "on the same side of the $z$-axis as $x$"? (or the $x$-axis)

Comment: @Comol. No, I don't think I do. The $y$-axis divides this plane in two, and the circle intersects each half of the plane once, in $p_1$ and $p_2$. $x$ lies in one of the halves. $p$ is whichever of $p_1$ and $p_2$ lies on the same half as $x$, which is to say, on the same side of the $y$-axis.

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I got it. I misunderstood that $x$ and $p$ are on the same side of the $y$-axis means that the $y$-coordinates of $x$ and $p$ have the same sign. Thanks.

Comment: You have a great power of visualization, Arthur: bravo! (And +1)