# $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ deformation retracts to $S^2 \bigvee S^1$. How?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

We know $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ deformation retract of $D^3\setminus S^1$. It is ok. $D^3\setminus S^1$ can be thought like a solid torus and D^2. How can i imagine?

Comment: You can see Algebraic Topology, Hatcher page 46, example 1.23.

Comment: @RobArthan: I'm sorry, but that's not correct. Take first homology, for instance. To OP: Can you first prove it deformation retracts onto the sphere Union the z-axis?

Comment: @MikeMiller: thanks. Brain not working three-dimensionally tonight $\ddot{\frown}$.

Comment: @RobArthan: My personal crutch is to just think about complements in $S^3$, which are usually easier since knot complements in $S^3$ are always $K(\pi,1)$s. Now if $K$ is a knot and $X$ is its complement in $S^3$, then you can prove that its complement in $\Bbb R^3$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee X$. That's the general reason a wedge $S^2$ shows up.

Comment: I've asked this question before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234070/mathbbr3-setminus-a-deformation-retracts-onto-s1-vee-s2?rq=1