# Meaning of $S^1 \vee S^2$ in Van Kampen Theory Context

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am self studying Algebraic Topology, and trying to understand Van Kampen theorem. Here is the exceprt from the book by Hatcher.

[image]

I can understand the line saying, all points outside of $S^2$ can be deformation retracted to $S^2$, by following:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2, r=[1, 1/t]$$

as $t$ goes from $0 \to 1$.

I can understand, please correct me if I am wrong, the logic via which points inside $S^2 - A$ can be contracted to $S^2$ and the diameter by drawing a cylinder inside circle A with axis along diameter (2nd figure), and slowly contracting it to the diameter, and rest of the points to $S^2$. So far good.

But I am stuck in the meaning of $S^1 \vee S^2$. Now $S^1$ is a unit circle by definition, e.g. the equator of $S^2$ as in the figure is valid member of $S^1$. But the example took the loop which goes within the circle A as a member of $S^1$, now this member is NOT unit radius. Also if someone argue that the equator can be "homotopied" to this loop, can't be done as the space we are talking does not allow homotopy as the space is discontinuous (circle A is removed). So what exactly is the meaning of this wedge sum, I am lost from the $S^1$ angle. Also this wedge sum does not talk about which points(or lines) are equivalent so that we can glue them together to get the resultant wedge sum.

What am I missing here? Your support is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $S^1$ may be embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ in many different ways, not just as a unit circle.

Comment: can you please provide an example ?@Arthur

Comment: Draw a closed, simple loop anywhere in space. That is $S^1$ embedded in $\Bbb R^3$. It doesn't have to have unit radius, and it doesn't even have to be a circle. Cut a potato in half, and look at the boundary of the surface of the cut as part of your room, and that's $S^1$ embedded in $\Bbb R^3$. As for the deformation retraction in the first part, I wrote an explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234070/mathbbr3-setminus-a-deformation-retracts-onto-s1-vee-s2/) that might or might not help you.

Comment: I think what you are saying is basically homotopying a circle to any closed loop in real space. That is OK. In $ℝ^3$ it is possible. But in $ℝ^3 - A$, how can I get to such homotopy, which is continuous deformation.

Comment: The [Borromean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings) are three $S^1$s embedded into $\Bbb R^3$. $S^1$ is a topological space, here it is not to be viewed as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$, but abstractly. In the way you are thinking about it three $S^1$s embedded into $\Bbb R^3$ doesn't make sense, as they would all have to be the same $S^1$.