# ${\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus A)}$ where $A$ is a circle in ${\mathbb{R}^3}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

So I was looking around for example fundamental group calculations, and I came across this one (${\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus A)}$ where ${A}$ is a circle in ${\mathbb{R}^3}$). Apparently, this deformation retracts to ${S_1\vee S_2}$, but I can't see how / what deformation retract exactly the author had in mind. I've looked around here on Stack Exchange, and there are other explanations of the fundamental group, but I wanted to specifically understand what exactly the deformation retract is, since the author gives other similar examples using deformation retracts I also wanted to understand. If anyone could help describe in a bit more detail what deformation retract is being used exactly, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234070/81360).

Comment: @BenGrossmann ah this is exactly what I wanted! I must not have looked hard enough, how did you find this so quickly? Haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: It popped up in the "related" column on the right. I'm not sure if there's a way to benefit from the search power of the full related column without posting the question first

Comment: @BenGrossmann ah I see, I'll have to keep an eye on that in future. I have closed my question for now as duplicate. Thanks again!